# Avoid html tags in laravel string validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to prevent users of using html tags in their username fields when they are registering, **how can I do that?**

For instance currently I have a user he registered with such username

```
E7JfyqxE4lsbqQ <html><a href="https://www.apple.com"><img src="https://...../d28/2011/19/93045d3fb9c4.jpg" width="600" height="234" alt="bill"></a> </html>
```

I just want to allow letters and numbers (a-z, 0-9) that's all.

`RegisterController`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users|not_exist',
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: try to use [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-not-regex) and include in the regex the <> within this role

Comment: @codeformoney you mean like this? `'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'not_regex:<>'],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to allow alphanumeric characters, you can use Laravel's built in [`alpha_num`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-alpha-num) validation.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'alpha_num', 'max:255'],
        'username' => 'required|string|alpha_num|max:255|unique:users|not_exist',
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => [
          'required',
          'string',
          'max:255',
          'string',
          'unique:users',
          'not_exist',
          'not_regex:<\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>'
        ],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

You can add more regex if you have more to include